# jQuery contains from input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, keyup

I have simple `jQuery` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#faqsearch" ).keyup(function() {
        var xyz = $( '#faqsearch' ).val();
        $(".faqtitle:contains(xyz)").css("background","yellow");
    });
});
```

Why I cannot get variable (in contains) from `xyz`?

Comment: Here in the above code xyz is considering a string. Replace contains(xyz) with contains("+xyz+") as xyz is a variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are passing the literal string of "xyz" instead of the variable xyz...

try changing it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#faqsearch" ).keyup(function() {
        var xyz = $( '#faqsearch' ).val();
        $(".faqtitle:contains(" + xyz + ")").css("background","yellow");
    });
});
```

Comment: It is going to take more than that. Certain characters in the input will break it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `.filter()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#faqsearch" ).keyup(function() {
        // If empty, clear backgrounds and stop
        if(!$(this).val()) {
            $(".faqtitle").css("background","none");
            return false;
        }

        // Get string
        var xyz = $(this).val();

        $(".faqtitle")
        .css("background","none")         // Clear backgrounds
        .filter(function() {              // Filter for elements that contain xyz
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(xyz) >= 0
        }).css("background","yellow");    // Set background
    });
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/9v8y7nvf/1/